# How much disk space would take to list every possible UEI-48 or MAC address?

Tags: networking

Is it (2^48) possible addresses X 48 bits = 1536 terabytes ??

Comment: Why would you want a list of all the numbers from 0 to 2^48 (281 474 976 710 656)?

Comment: `0:1:2^48` takes about 9 bytes in my reckoning (including the terminating `'\0'` character). It's called utilizing entropy to compress your data - very useful for storing large amount of organized data. It's like storing `314159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706` as "first 100 digits of pi".

Answer (score 2):

There are 2<sup>48</sup> (281474976710656) possible EUI-48 addresses, which would occupy 2<sup>48</sup> × 48 bits or 1688849860263936 eight-bit bytes, which is 1536 terabytes or 1.5 petabytes.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds about right.

Plus some Bytes for the filesystem.

And a lot more bytes if you want to store everything as textfile. In this case we are talking about 2^48 (address range) * 48 bit (per address) * 8 bit (per char, assuming you store everything in ASCII) = about 12288 terabytes.
And don't forget dividers between the single addresses - if required.

Comment: If you're going to store in ASCII, you wouldn't store '0' or '1' for everything, you'd use hex.  With 8-bit chars, you cut the expansion from 8:1 to 8:4, or 2.  48-bit address is 12 hex digits; 96 bits with 8bit characters or 84 with seven-bit ASCII.  You could put two 48-bit addresses into 21 bytes of storage, even with character encoding.